# What is the most Rails'ish way of handling multiple layouts/views for the same controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actioncontroller

The scenario is this:

I have some users on my site. A user has a role, the relevant ones here is `admin` and `normal`. I also have a model, let's call it `SomeModel`.

I have created a backend for the site, which uses an **admin** layout. All admins have full access to edit any content.

The problem arises with this relation: **User -> owns -> SomeModel**. That means a non admin  **User** can own an instance of `SomeModel` and should be able to edit the data of this instance.

The controller for `SomeModel` has an edit action which then caters to both admins and regular users.

However, I don't want regular users seing the **admin** layout and right now, the way I do this is like so:

```
if current_user.admin?
  render :layout => 'admin'
end
```

Which defaults to the standard layout if the user is not an admin. I have this in all my actions for `SomeModel` and it just doesn't seem like a very Rails way of doing things.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this at the controller level:

```
  class MyModelController < ActionController::Base
    layout :user_or_admin_layout

    def index
      # fetching objects
    end

    private
      def user_or_admin_layout
        current_user.admin? ? "admin_layout" : "user_layout"
      end
  end
```

There are more examples in the rails documentation for [layout](http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M000242&name=layout)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I skipped over that part of the documentation, this definitely feels "cleaner".